# Prevent Eclipse (RAD) from generating code automaticly

Tags: eclipse, wsdl, client

I am working on a project, I have imported a jar file with the class files needed to connect to a web service, then added the wsdl to my project.  The problem now is eclipse(rad) is generating java files, that I don't need and causing issues as the object already exist in the jar file.  How to I prevent Eclipse(RAD) from auto generating java files from the wsdl, as I have wasted 2 days trying to force Eclipse(RAD) from generating these files, as they are unneeded and causing compile problems.

Comment: In Eclipse stuff is incrementally created/built by the project builders that can be deactivated in _Project > Properties: Builders_.

Comment: Now on to the builders, I have in there
JavaScript validator, Java Build, Faceted Project Validation Builder, Validation, Maven Project Build.
nothing about wsdl class generation

Comment: _"I have wasted 2 days trying to force Eclipse(RAD) from generating these files"_ So, what did you do in those two days? What did you try and what documentation did you read in those two days? Does it not work as documented or did you not find or read the documentation? I asked you this before, but it was deleted. Tell me why am I not allowed to ask you this?

Comment: I have tried not listing the WSDL location in the web.xml, that causes the web server to complain that there was no WSDL listed, I tried not putting the WSDL in the project, that caused a File not found.  I tried makeing the directories read only, Eclipse(RAD) ignored that and wrote the files.  I tried fidling with the Mavin pom.xml file and adding excludeds to it in the build sections and pluggins for excluding file generation. Tried turning off verisous options in Eclipse.  Tried emptying out the wsdl file so it would be there but with no data (but this also caused issues during run time)

Comment: Also looked at each option for the service-ref tag in the web.xml to see if one of them is causing the generation.

Comment: Also I should note I have worked with others in the origination to try to solve this, and so far of those I have talked to no joy.  I have sent out to them links to our private bitbucket to others in our origination (I can not post preparatory code here, but with others in my origination I been able to share with them.)

Comment: Also I should note for the 16 hours not all 16 hours have been on this as I had 5 hours of meetings during those days (we are agile that why so many hours of meetings, I do more meetings in a week now that the higher ups decided to go agile then I had per month when we were still waterfall)

Comment: Finnally figured out a solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with.  The issue is that it is not Maven causing this, this is Eclipse(RAD)  my objects were in a package such as com.thispackage.servicename.v2 (upgrading from v1 to v2) but the name space in the wsdl was http://servicename.thispackage.com/v2 .  as Mavin is not running the wsdl2java, there is no problem, I changed the name space to http://v2.servicename.thispackage.com When Eclipse compiles the wsdl2java fails as the objects already exist in a jar file (so it can not overwrite them) But Eclipse(RAD) will continue on with the compilation and deployment to local server.  I just have to click OK to acknowledge the error but everything works as intended.

Not a great solution, and I will have to document it in the README.md (or find a real solution later) but this lets me do the real work I need to do, before I deal with this detail.